# Cancel drag action JavaFX

Tags: events, javafx, drag-and-drop

In my JavaFX application I support drag and drop either from OS to my app, either from inside the app. The following behavior is what I would like to accomplish:

- If the user starts dragging from inside my app and he leaves my main window with the mouse (leaving my app), I would like to cancel the drag action, so even if he comes back with the cursor, he does not fire any dragover events (for example).

I believe I have to trigger some event of some kind on dragExitted on my main window.Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe, if the dragged exit the bounds of the app consume event?

Comment: Even if I consume the event, I'm consuming just the dragExitted event....it doesn't cancel the drag action. When it comes back, it will still trigger "dragEntered", "dragOver" and "dragDropped"

Comment: Just a guess: clear the dragboard on mouse exit?

Comment: Yes, tried this, but it still triggers the mentioned events, it just doesn't drop anything if the mouse is released. Visually the user still sees that he's dragging something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something you can play with. I think it does what you need.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;
import javafx.scene.text.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class ConsumeDragEvent extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {

        final Text source = new Text(50, 100, "DRAG ME");
        final Text target = new Text(300, 100, "DROP HERE");

        final boolean[] hasBeenOffScreen = {false};




        source.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                /* drag was detected, start a drag-and-drop gesture*/
                /* allow any transfer mode */
                hasBeenOffScreen[0] = false;
                Dragboard db = source.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);

                ((Node) event.getSource()).setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
                /* Put a string on a dragboard */
                ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                content.putString(source.getText());
                db.setContent(content);

                event.consume();
            }
        });        


        source.setOnDragDone(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                /* the drag and drop gesture ended */
                /* if the data was successfully moved, clear it */
                if (event.getTransferMode() == TransferMode.MOVE) {
                    source.setText("");
                }
                event.consume();
            }
        });


        target.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                /* data is dragged over the target */
                /* accept it only if it is not dragged from the same node 
                 * and if it has a string data */
                if (event.getGestureSource() != target &&
                        event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                    /* allow for moving */
                    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
                }

                event.consume();
            }
        });

        target.setOnDragEntered(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
            /* the drag-and-drop gesture entered the target */
            /* show to the user that it is an actual gesture target */
                 if (event.getGestureSource() != target &&
                         event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                     target.setFill(Color.GREEN);
                 }

                 event.consume();
            }
        });

        target.setOnDragExited(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                /* mouse moved away, remove the graphical cues */
                target.setFill(Color.BLACK);

                event.consume();
            }
        });

        target.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                /* data dropped */
                /* if there is a string data on dragboard, read it and use it */
                System.out.println(hasBeenOffScreen[0]);
                if(hasBeenOffScreen[0] == true)
                {
                    event.setDropCompleted(false);

                }
                else
                {
                    Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
                    boolean success = false;
                    if (db.hasString()) {
                       target.setText(db.getString());
                       success = true;
                    }
                    /* let the source know whether the string was successfully 
                     * transferred and used */
                    event.setDropCompleted(success);
                }


                event.consume();
             }
        });


        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.getChildren().addAll(source, target);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
//        scene.setOnDragOver(event -> {
//            
//                scene.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
//                System.out.println(event.getX());
//                System.out.println(scene.getX());
//                System.out.println(scene.getWidth());
//                
//                if(event.getX() >= scene.getWidth())
//                {
//                    System.out.println("Out of scene!");
//                   // Dragboard db = source.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
//                     hasBeenOffScreen[0] = true;
//                    event.consume();
//                }
//          });     

        scene.setOnDragExited(event ->{
            hasBeenOffScreen[0] = true;
            System.out.println("Off scene!");

        });
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    class Delta{double x, y;}
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. As I can see, you just simulate to the user that he's not dragging anything, just a visual thing, right? I'll check if there are no other ways to actually cancel the drag action and if not, I'll accept your answer as it may be the only solution for this.